# How do I turn recursive part of function into threading?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int meets_criteria(char * entry_name, char * name) {
    int criteria_met = 0;
    if (name != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(entry_name, name) == 0) {
            criteria_met = 1;
        }
    }
    return criteria_met;
}
void find(char * where, char * name)  {
    DIR * dir;
    struct dirent * entry;
    char * e_name;
    char path[1024];
    char curr_dir[] = ".";
    char pre_dir[] = "..";
    int e_type;
    int is_dots;
    dir = opendir(where);
    if (dir) {
        while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            e_type = entry -> d_type;
            e_name = entry -> d_name;
            is_dots = strcmp(e_name, curr_dir) == 0 || strcmp(e_name, pre_dir) == 0;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path),"%s/%s", where, e_name);
            if (!is_dots) {
                if (meets_criteria(e_name, name)) {
                    printf("%s\n", path);
                }
                if (e_type == DT_DIR) {
                    find(path, name);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
}
int main () {
    char *where;
    char *name;
    char c[1024];
    char d[1024];
    printf("Enter dir\n");
    scanf("%s", c);
    where = c;
    printf("Enter file\n");
    scanf("%s", d);
    name = d;
    find(where, name);
    


 return 0;
}
```

I have this code that does the following. Pass in a directory to start searching for a file.
Pass in a string of a name of the file you want to “find” in your filesystem on your machine.
Start at the given directory and for each file that matches the search string, print the absolute path + filename to the screen.

I want to take the program and add threading in place of the recursive part of the find function. I'm having problem spawning detached threads and ensuring they properly run without locks or any limitations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `entry -> d_type` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `entry->d_type`.

Comment: You should show your best effort so far.  Directory hierarchies in the absence of symlinks are separate (and you're not following symlinks), so it is legitimate to use a thread to analyze the contents of each directory found.  You simply need to ensure that you pass the information to the thread function appropriately.  Since you're on Linux, you'll be using POSIX threads (pthreads).  The thread function is given a single `void *` argument.  The argument must not change.  You'll also need to keep track of the threads you start so you can release memory, and wait for them to terminate.

Comment: Why do you think detached threads are appropriate?  They probably aren't.